# Identifying DNS packets

Tags: sockets, unix, networking, dns

When looking a packet byte code, how would you identify a dns packet.
The IP header's protocol field would tell that a UDP frame follows, but inside the UDP frame no protocol field exists to specify what comes next and, from what I can see, there is nothing inside the frame that would uniquely identify it as a dns packet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Other than it being on port 53, there's a few things you can look out for which might give a *hint* that you're looking at DNS traffic.

I will refer to the field names used in §4.1 of [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) a lot here:

```
                                1  1  1  1  1  1
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  1  2  3  4  5
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      ID                       |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    QDCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ANCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    NSCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ARCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

As you can see above the header is 12 bytes long - a 2 byte ID, 2 bytes of flags, and 4 x 2 bytes of counts.

In any DNS packet the `QDCOUNT` field will be exactly one (`0x0001`).  Technically other values are allowed by the protocol, but in practise they are never used.

In a query (`QR == 0`) the `ANCOUNT` and `NSCOUNT` values will be exactly zero (`0x0000`), and the `ARCOUNT` will typically be 0, 1, or 2, depending on whether `EDNS0` [(RFC 2671)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2671)and `TSIG` [(RFC 2845)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2845) are being used.  `RCODE` will also be zero in a query.

Responses are somewhat harder to identify, unless you're observing both sides of the conversation and can correlate each response to the query that triggered it.

Obviously the `QR` bit will be set, and as above the `QDCOUNT` should still be one.  The remaining counters however will have many and varied permutations.  However it's *exceedingly* unlikely that any of the counters will be greater than 255, so you should be able to rely on bytes 4, 6, 8 and 10 all being zero.

Following the headers you'll start to find resource records, the first one being the actual question that was asked (§4.1.2).  The unfortunate part here is that the designers of the protocol saw fit to include a *variable length* label field (`QNAME`) in front of two fixed fields (`QTYPE` and `QCLASS`).

[To further complicate matters labels can be *compressed*, using a *backwards* pointer to somewhere else in the packet.  Fortunately you will almost never see a compressed label in the Question Section, since by definition you can't go backwards from there.  Technically a perverse implementor could send a compression pointer back into the header, but that shouldn't happen].

So, start reading each length byte and then skip that many bytes until you reach a null byte, and then the next two 16 bit words will be `QTYPE` and `QCLASS`.   There are very few [legal values](http://www.iana.org/assignments/dns-parameters) for `QCLASS`, and almost all packets will contain the value `1` for `IN` ("Internet").  You may *occasionally* see `3` for `CH` (Chaos).

That's it for now - if I think of anything else I'll add it later.

Comment: What about checking that the opcode/Z bits are set correctly? The opcode for example is 4 bits but has only 3 valid values (0, 1, and 2).

Comment: OpCode has *four* assigned (non-obsolete) values, and they're 0, 4, 5 and 6.

Answer (score -5):

How about checking the port number? Should be 53 for both source and target port.

Comment: no, it'll be port 53 for _one_ of source or destination.  Some older resolvers did send queries _from_ port 53 but it's now considered very bad practise to use a constant source port (cf. Kaminsky bug).